# Is there a way to map from one input document to many output documents in the Mongo aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For a project I'm working on, I need to generate two interpretations of each retrieved record and then calculate the average (and standard of deviation) over all of the interpretations. The easiest way to do this would be through the aggregation pipeline, but I've been unable to find any aggregation stages that provide this functionality. Some like "project" map from one input document to one output document, while others like "group" map from many input documents to a single output document, but I haven't found any that map from one input document to many output documents. Do any such aggregation stages exist? If not, how would I go about creating a using the desired document set?

Comment: Depends on what mapping you are looking for.  If you have a separate process to generate each you might try "$facet", if you just need to split each document into many in the pipeline, use `$addFields` to add an array, then `$unwind` the array.

Comment: Please post a sample document, so as to understand the nature of mapping. Aggregation allows many ways to transform the documents - mapping, filtering, reducing, faceting, etc are some things one can perform using the [Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/index.html).

Comment: I'm going to apply a few different variations of the process, but the first one looks like this. I have documents in the form {User:u, Item:i, Rating:r, Ev:e, Sd: s} and after matching on user it would generate {User:u, Item:i, Rating:r - 0.5, Ev:e, Sd: s} and {User:u, Item:i, Rating:r + 0.5, Ev:e, Sd: s}.